# In Kotlin, Why can the value of a val integer be reassigned by the inc() method?

Tags: kotlin, variables, variable-assignment, readonly, val

Consider the following,

`val x: Int = 0`

`val` variables cannot be changed so doing `x += 1` wouldn't work

The compiler says `Val cannot be reassigned`

why then does `x.inc()` work fine

doesn't `x.inc()` reassign the value from `0` to `1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x.inc()` does not increment the variable `x`. Instead, it *returns* a value that is one more than the value of `x`. It does not change `x`.

```
val x = 0
x.inc() // 1 is retuned, but discarded here
print(x) // still 0!
```

As its [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/inc.html) says:

> Returns this value incremented by one.

That might seem like a very useless method. Well, this is what Kotlin uses to implement operator overloading for the postfix/prefix `++` operator.

When you do `a++`, for example, the following happens:

> - Store the initial value of `a` to a temporary storage `a0`.
> - Assign the result of `a0.inc()` to `a`.
> - Return `a0` as the result of the expression.

Here you can see how `inc`'s return value is used.